# Generate Web Page Using PHP Class

Tags: php, oop

I am a university student experimenting with OOP and PHP.  I was wanting to build up a page using a BuildPage class.

```
<?php
Class BuildPage {
  private $title;
  private $style;
  private $head;
  private $header;
  private $page;
  private $footer;
  private $finalPage;

  public function __construct($title, $style)
  {
    $this->title = $title;
    $this->style = $style;
  }

  public function addHead()
  {
  $this->head = "
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>$this->title</title>
    <link href='$this->style' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

  </head>";

  }  

  public function addToPage($partOfPage)
  {
    if(empty($this->page) || !isset($this->page))
  {
    $this->page = $partOfPage;
  }
  else {
    $this->page .= "<br> " . $partOfPage;
    }
  }

  public function addHeader($header)
  {
    $this->header = "<body><div class='container'><header> " . $header . " 
    </header>";
  }

  public function addFooter($footer)
  {
    $this->footer .= "<BR><footer> " . $footer . " </footer></div></body>
    </html>";
  }

  public function getPage()
  {
    $this->finalPage = $this->head . $this->header . $this->page . 
    $this->footer;
    return $this->finalPage;
  }
}

?>
```

However, when I try to build the page using the functions, I cannot understand how to use PHP within the argument as below:

```
$buildPage->addToPage("
<!-- Here is our page's main content -->
  <!-- Use function to display songs -->

 <?php $music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml'); ?>

");
```

If I escape the $ like \$ to try and make it a string, for some reason the  becomes a comment in HTML.  Is it possible for this approach to work at all?

Many Thanks

EDIT:

This is the index page below, i call the class at the bottom with an echo.

```
<?php
require_once('phpclasses/Connect.php');
require_once('phpclasses/BuildPage.php');
require_once('phpclasses/MusicIE.php');

$dbconnect = new Connect(); 
$music = new MusicIE();
$buildPage = new BuildPage("Music Website", "style.css");


$buildPage->addHead();
$buildPage->addHeader("
<!-- Here is the main header that is used accross all the pages of my 
website 
-->
<div class='PageHeading'>Available Music Listed Below:</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Register</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<form>
<input type='search' name='q' placeholder='Search query'>
<input type='submit' value='Go!'>
</form>
");
$buildPage->addToPage("
<!-- Here is our page's main content -->
  <!-- Use function to display songs -->

 " . $music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml'));

$buildPage->addFooter("
<!-- And here is my footer that is used across all the pages of our website 
-->
  <p>©Copyright 2017 by Kris Wilson. All rights reversed.</p>
");

echo $buildPage->getPage();
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing a string to the function `BuildPage::addToPage($partOfPage)` you could try to pass the result of `$music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml')` instead of the literal function call as a string. Like so:

```
$buildPage->addToPage("
<!-- Here is our page's main content -->
  <!-- Use function to display songs -->

 ". $music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml'));
```

Comment: I edited my original question, if I do as you suggested, it displays the results outside of the HTML at the very top of the page

Comment: alter $music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml')) so it does not echo the string but instead returns it

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your code is wrong on the `addToPage` function call. you should call it like this:

```
$buildPage->addToPage("
<!-- Here is our page's main content -->
  <!-- Use function to display songs -->

 ".$music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml'));
```

You should add the `$music->displaySongs('xmlfiles/songs.xml')` output to the end of the string.